# Difference between sc start ... and Start-Service ... in PowerShell 2

Tags: service, powershell-2.0, windows-server-2003

I have a few different services installed on the same machine.  I'm writing a PowerShell 2 script to start and stop them.

For some of the services, I can use `Start-Service -displayname "the service"` to successfully start it.  On others, using the `Start-Service` cmdlet causes and error along the lines of "Cannot start service ... on computer '.'".

In the cases that I get an error using the `Start-Service` cmdlet, `sc start "the service"` always succeeds.

Vice versa is also true (although `sc start` doesn't return any errors--it just doesn't start the service at all.)

Is there any difference between these commands?  Is there an alternative command I should be using?  Finally, can I 'catch' any errors from the cmdlet and just include both commands to cover all the bases?

This problem is repeatable for me, even if I uninstall and reinstall the service.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure the differences between `sc start` and `start-service`, but you can use wmi to do what you want.

To start the service:

```
(get-wmiobject win32_service -filter "name='the service'").startService()
```

To stop the service:

```
(get-wmiobject win32_service -filter "name='the service'").stopService()
```

To check the status of a service, you can use:

```
get-wmiobject win32_service -filter "name='the service'"
```

It will show you the state and also the start mode.  If you want to automate this, you can use the following.

To stop the service:

```
if ((get-wmiobject win32_service -filter "name='the service'").state -eq "Running") {
    (get-wmiobject win32_service -filter "name='the service'").stopService()
} # Stops the service if it is running
```

To start the service:

```
if ((get-wmiobject win32_service -filter "name='the service'").state -eq "Stopped") {
    (get-wmiobject win32_service -filter "name='the service'").startService()
} # starts the service if it is stopped
```

I'm sure you can modify those to suit your needs.

The reason I like to use wmi is the ability to specify `-computername` and `-credentials`.  It makes it so you can access a remote system and authenticate to it if you have non-domain systems.  Hope that helped.  Have a great day!

Answer (score 4):

In powershell `sc` is `Set-Content`. see with `help sc`, its not he same as when you run `sc` in `cmd.exe`.

You probably want to look at `Start-Service`, `Restart-Service`, `Stop-Service`.
Use `Get-Command` to help you find the commandlet you'll need:

```
PS C:\> Get-Command | findstr Service
Cmdlet   Get-Service           Microsoft.PowerShell.Management
Cmdlet   New-Service           Microsoft.PowerShell.Management
Cmdlet   New-WebServiceProxy   Microsoft.PowerShell.Management
Cmdlet   Restart-Service       Microsoft.PowerShell.Management
Cmdlet   Resume-Service        Microsoft.PowerShell.Management
Cmdlet   Set-Service           Microsoft.PowerShell.Management
Cmdlet   Start-Service         Microsoft.PowerShell.Management
Cmdlet   Stop-Service          Microsoft.PowerShell.Management
Cmdlet   Suspend-Service       Microsoft.PowerShell.Management
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be related to the reason why `sc start` wasn't working in some cases:
http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/powershell-faqs/q-do-normal-windows-commands-run-in-powershell

Perhaps I needed to call it like this:
`& "sc start 'the service'"`

Comment: `PS> cmd --% /c sc query wsearch` --% = bypass the parser and just append it to whatever cmd resolves to, cmd /c is Run command and exit